# CSS overflow-y for deeply nested divs

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm trying to understand how come my deepest two divs aren't scrolling in the y-direction.

It's a 2 column layout nested within another 2 column layout, essentially looking like 3 columns. I've also made a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/samesmail/pen/qKdyNE?editors=1100) to demonstrate my exact architecture:

My current solution applies an `overflow-y: scroll` to the two divs I want to scroll and all parent divs have been applied with `max-height: 100%; overflow: hidden`.

Why doesn't this work? What is the best approach I should take?

```css
html body {
  margin: 0;
}
#app {
  padding-top: 60px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: black;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
}
#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: cyan;
}
.route-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.2fr 0.8fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "sidemenu container";
  
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  background: magenta;
}
.outer-side-menu {
  background: orange;
  grid-area: sidemenu;
}
.outer-container {
  grid-area: container;
  background: yellow;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px auto;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "tab-menu"
    "tab-container";
  
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.tab-menu {
  grid-area: tab-menu;
  background: red;
}
.tab-container {
  grid-area: tab-container;
  background: purple;
  
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.35fr 0.65fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: "inner-menu inner-content";
  
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  font-size: 144px;
  background: teal;
}
.inner-menu {
  grid-area: inner-menu;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: pink;

}
.inner-content {
  grid-area: inner-content;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="navbar">Navigation</div>
  <div class="route-container">
    <div class="outer-side-menu">Side Menu</div>
    <div class="outer-container">
      <div class="tab-menu">
        Tabs
      </div>
      <div class="tab-container">
        <div class="content-container">
          <div class="inner-menu">
            Inner Menu
            Inner Menu
            Inner Menu
            Inner Menu
            Inner Menu
            Inner Menu
            Inner Menu
            Inner Menu
            Inner Menu
          </div>
          <div class="inner-content">
            Inner Content 
            Inner Content 
            Inner Content 
            Inner Content
            Inner Content
            Inner Content
            Inner Content
            Inner Content
            Inner Content
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your deepest two divs aren't scrolling because they aren't actually overfilling. If you checkout the height on these two divs (and the height of the parent divs), you can see they are nearly 3000px tall, with enough room for all of your text.

[Dev Tools showing the height of one of the divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUXUt.png)

They appear to be constricted to a small size because the overflow of the `.route-container` is hidden. See:

```
.route-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 0.2fr 0.8fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas: "sidemenu container";
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: magenta;
}
```

To resolve this, I would use `display: flex;` instead of `display: grid;`. The result allowed for those two boxes to scroll individually.

```
html body {
    margin: 0;
}

#app {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#navbar {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 20vh;
    background: cyan;
}

.route-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background: magenta;
    height: 85vh;
}

.outer-side-menu {
    background: orange;
    width: 100%;
}

.outer-container {
    background: yellow;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.tab-menu {
    background: red;
}

.tab-container {
    background: purple;
}

.content-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    max-height: 75vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 144px;
    background: teal;
}

.inner-menu {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: pink;
}

.inner-content {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: teal;
}
```

Grid is probably too restrictive to allow the inner divs to scroll without also scrolling the 'Tabs' and 'Side Menu' altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out. The problem was my understanding of `height`. Child divs weren't adopting the full height they were contained in. I needed to use `position` along with `top`, `left`, `bottom`, `right`.

See the following [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eKNbvZ?editors=0100)

Answer (score 0):

Added     `height: calc(100vh - 109px);` to inner-menu and inner-content div

```
 Total height of window - (height of Tab bar + Navigation bar)
```

```css
html body {
  margin: 0;
}
#app {
  padding-top: 60px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: black;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
}
#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: cyan;
}
.route-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.2fr 0.8fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "sidemenu container";
  
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  background: magenta;
}
.outer-side-menu {
  background: orange;
  grid-area: sidemenu;
}
.outer-container {
  grid-area: container;
  background: yellow;
  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50px auto;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "tab-menu"
    "tab-container";
  
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.tab-menu {
  grid-area: tab-menu;
  background: red;
}
.tab-container {
  grid-area: tab-container;
  background: purple;
  
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.35fr 0.65fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: "inner-menu inner-content";
  
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  font-size: 144px;
  background: teal;
}
.inner-menu {
  grid-area: inner-menu;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: pink;
  height: calc(100vh - 109px); // Total height of window - height of top elements

}
.inner-content {
  grid-area: inner-content;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: teal;
  height: calc(100vh - 109px);
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="navbar">Navigation</div>
  <div class="route-container">
    <div class="outer-side-menu">Side Menu</div>
    <div class="outer-container">
      <div class="tab-menu">
        Tabs
      </div>
      <div class="tab-container">
        <div class="content-container">
          <div class="inner-menu">
            Inner Menu
            Inner Menu
            Inner Menu
            Inner Menu
            Inner Menu
            Inner Menu
            Inner Menu
            Inner Menu
            Inner Menu
          </div>
          <div class="inner-content">
            Inner Content 
            Inner Content 
            Inner Content 
            Inner Content
            Inner Content
            Inner Content
            Inner Content
            Inner Content
            Inner Content
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but is there a solution where divs don’t know anything about their parent divs?

Comment: Sorry I dont have such a solution.Even I dont like this solution much. You can wait may be someone else comes up with a better solution. :)

Comment: Any luck with what you wanted?

Comment: yes, i posted a solution above but still have some discrepancies. It gets messed up if the frame gets resized :/

Comment: Sorry i dont have MAC . Cant help you with safari